# Fermat generalization, not sure if it's true or how to prove it

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I have this rule in my notebook, but I don't remember when I took it:

$$a^{p^n}$$ is congruent with **a(p)** (a modulo p), where **p** is a prime number, **a** is an integer and **n** is a natural number.

Or, in other words, that:

$$p | a^{p^n} - a$$

I can't find this rule in Internet. It's supposed to be a generalization of Fermat Little Theorem.

Is this true? If so, how can be derivated from Fermat Little Theorem?

Comment: Follows trivially from Fermat Little Theorem and $p-1\mid p^n-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermat's (little) theorem is: If $p$ doesn't divide $a$ then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1$ mod $p.$ When  both sides multiplied by $a$ it becomes $a^p \equiv a$ mod $p$ and now one can allow $a$ divisible by $p.$ At this point apply an inductive argument, next case being $(a^p)^p \equiv a^p,$ then use inductive hypothesis to finish. Higher powers go similarly, each going down to the previous power.

Comment: Isn't it $(a^p)^p\equiv a^p$?

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Yes, will fix.

Comment: Your answer allowed me to understand this property. I didn't feel confortable using it without knowing how it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @hhaamm No problem. Glad it helped. The comment of Minz also leads to a simple proof.